# I am trying to set a series name dynamicallly in amcharts

Tags: line, series, amcharts4

I passing data into a line series but I cannot dynamically add anything to series.name I just get the string rather that teh variable. 
I tried using  .dataFields.name but this is teh incorrect syntax. 
Please advise?
J

```
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value"+ seriesId;
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.name = "BrandNM"+ seriesId;
series.strokeWidth = 2;
```

Comment: You can't set it dynamically using a property from your data, if that's what you're attempting to do. You need to set it directly to the desired value.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm that is a little limiting. I will have to do an if statement then to pick up the values then :(